# Is it possible to route a Webmethod?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, routes

I have a .aspx page with some Webmethods that I use for jQuery ajax calls.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string HelloWorld(string s) {
    return "Hello"+ s;
}
```

And call this with Url: `/ajax/Test.aspx/HelloWorld`

I wonder if it is possible to route this method to another url like `/ajax/helloworld/`?

Comment: that's an asp.net question, not jQuery. What version are you using? MVC, maybe?

Comment: Sorry, my first post here... No I am using ASP.NET 4.0, not MVC.

Comment: Welcome. You're doing OK: formatted code and everything.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, WebMethods don't work transparently with the Routing framework.  There is a work around. You have to access the PageMethods directly by doing the following in your javascript:

```
PageMethods.set_path('/the/path/to/your/page.aspx');
PageMethods.YourMethod(params, onSuccess, onFailure);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for the fix.

You don't have to specify the full path.  PageMethods.set_path('page.aspx'); works just fine.